# Shell script select record giving one extra row as column name

Tags: mysql, shell, sh

I have below function to read the data from mysql database:

```
get_all_server_ip_address(){
    mysql -h$MYSQL_HOST -u$DB_USER_NAME -p$DB_PASSWORD << EOF
    use $DB_SCHEMA;
    select ip_address from server;
    EOF
}
```

I am calling this function as below:

server_ip=`get_all_server_ip_address`

```
for ip in $server_ip
do
    echo $ip
done
```

Output:

ip_address

54.206.76.6

I have only "54.206.76.6" in my database and it returns ip_address i.e column name

[image]
Database screenshot

Comment: what is your problem elaborate...

Comment: Why I am getting column name "ip_address" when I am doing for loop

Answer (score 1):

use "--skip-column-names" option to login into mysql  and then query , for example :

```
mysql -uroot probe --skip-column-names -e 'select ip_address from TABLE_NAME limit 1'
```

Comment: I found it, I have to use "mysql -sN -h$MYSQL_HOST -u$DB_USER_NAME -p$DB_PASSWORD" i.e "-sN" parameter to mysql. Thanks